# this my code produce this error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNotes' in type cast can you identify the error

Tags: flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:mynote/auth_service.dart';

import 'package:mynote/services/notes_service.dart';

class NewNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewNoteView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewNoteView> createState() => _NewNoteViewState();
}

class _NewNoteViewState extends State<NewNoteView> {
  DatabaseNote? _note;

  late final NotesService _notesService;

  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNewNote() async {
    final existingNote = _note;

    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }

    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;

    final email = currentUser.email!;

    final owner = await _notesService.getUser(email: email);

    return await _notesService.createNote(owner: owner);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;

    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(id: note.id);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;

    final text = _textController.text;

    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        note: note,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();

    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();

    _textController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();

    _textController = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;

    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }

    final text = _textController.text;

    await _notesService.updateNote(
      note: note,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListner() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);

    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 145, 216),
        title: const Text('new notes'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createNewNote(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote;

              _setupTextControllerListner();

              return TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              );

            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this my code produce this error. type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNotes' in type cast can you identify the error

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess since you haven't provided the full error details such as Stack Trace.

But, skimming through the code I can see that line number 111 (in the shared snippet, given below) contains a type cast and possibly throwing this error.

```dart
_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote;
```

The `snapshot.data` can possibly be `null` which can cause this exception. Change the code to the following and see if it fixes:

```dart
_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote?;
```

Hope this helps!